# After Devexpress CallbackPanel PerformCallback, Ext Control isn't displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, ext.net

I want to use Ext.Net controls inside devexpress callbackpanel. When page is rendered first everything is OK, Ext controls are fine. But, when you refresh the callbackpanel with `PerformCallback()` function Ext Controls disappears. What is the solution?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="devex_ext._default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallbackPanel" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTabControl" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallbackPanel" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxPanel" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server" />

    <div style="clear:both">

    <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="ASPxCallbackPanel2" ClientInstanceName="cp" runat="server" Width="200px">
        <PanelCollection>
            <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent2" runat="server">
                <dx:ASPxPageControl ID="ASPxPageControl2" runat="server">
                    <TabPages>
                        <dx:TabPage  Text="Ext Linkbutton">
                            <ContentCollection>
                                <dx:ContentControl ID="ContentControl1" runat="server">
                                    <ext:LinkButton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server" Text="Linkbutton">
                                        <Listeners>
                                            <Click Handler="Ext.Msg.alert('Clicked', 'LinkButton');" />
                                        </Listeners>
                                    </ext:LinkButton>
                                </dx:ContentControl>
                            </ContentCollection>
                        </dx:TabPage>
                        <dx:TabPage  Text="Asp Button">
                            <ContentCollection>
                                <dx:ContentControl ID="ContentControl2" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />    
                                </dx:ContentControl>
                            </ContentCollection>
                        </dx:TabPage>
                    </TabPages>
                </dx:ASPxPageControl>
            </dx:PanelContent>
        </PanelCollection>
    </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>

    <ext:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="Refresh">
        <Listeners>
            <Click Handler="cp.PerformCallback()" />
        </Listeners>
    </ext:LinkButton>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would not work, because you have not specified the **ASPxCallbackPanel.ClientInstanceName** property (and have not enabled the client-side programmatic object).

Modify your markup as follows:

```
<dx:ASPxCallbackPanel ... ClientInstanceName="cp">


<Click Handler="cp.PerformCallback()" />
```

Check [this](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/CallbackPanel/CustomJavaScriptProperties.aspx) demo that illustrates how use the ASPxCallbackPanel container.

Comment: The problem is not that, I made as you advised, the same problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you wont to run javascript after callback use javascript prefix 'dxis_', look at this [topic](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18783)

You can add, for example div with specific id and then run script, that creates ExtJS controls, configuration which contains renderTo: 'specific di'